# Invalid HTTP GET request from iOS iPhone Facebook app

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, http, httprequest

I see these invalid HTTP requests in the server log.
The request URI includes scheme+hostname+port.

```
1.2.3.4  [13/Jan/2017:04:20:01 +0000]    GET http://www.DOMAIN.hu:80/munkaugyi-segedanyagok/minimalber-2017-kormanyrendelet HTTP/1.1     403     http://m.facebook.com   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14C92 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/75.0.0.48.61;FBBV/45926345;FBRV/46260258;FBDV/iPhone8,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iOS;FBSV/10.2;FBSS/2;FBCR/TelekomHU;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/5]
```

All other requests from the same visitor suggest a legitimate user.

Could it be the Facebook app for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out most webservers support **absolute request URI-s**.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.1

An HTTP client may send requests with absolute request URI-s like the ones in proxy requests but with the same domain name.

Comment: More on this in this WordPress core ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39586